# ws library connection doubled

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, ws

I have a problem on connection , I have a **express server** and create a `ws` instance passing the **express server** instance , when I connect, the connection was successful and try to send a message I can receive message once, and when I close the connection and connect again then send a message the message now send twice , and every time a keep doing this the message keeping doubled, my socket on a channel is just only one connection , I think its creating a new proccess ? How can I prevent this behavior ?

```js
/**
  * New WebScoket instance initialize
  * @type WebSocket
  */
 const ws = new WebSocket.Server({ /*verifyClient,*/ server });
 console.log('instantiate');
 const rooms = {};

/**
  * Add new collection
  * @param {String} room
  * @param {String} channel
  * @param {Object} socket
  * @returns {Undefined|Null}
  */
 function add(room, channel, socket) 
 {
  if(typeof rooms[room] == 'undefined') rooms[room] = {};
  if(typeof rooms[room][channel] == 'undefined') rooms[room][channel] = [];
  if(typeof rooms[room][channel] != 'undefined') rooms[room][channel].push(socket);
  redis.subscribe(`${room}-${channel}`);
  return;
 }

 /**
  * Add new properties to socket
  * @param {String} room
  * @param {String} channel
  * @return {Object}
  */
 function addPropToSocket(room, channel)
 {
  return {room, channel};
 }

 /**
  * Send message to user
  * @param  {String} room
  * @param  {String} channel
  * @param  {String} msg
  * @param  {Object} socket
  * @return {void}
  */
 function send(room, channel, msg, socket)
 {
  if(typeof rooms[room] == 'undefined') return;
  if(typeof rooms[room][channel] == 'undefined') return;
  rooms[room][channel].forEach(user => {
   // if(user !== socket && user.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) user.send(msg);
   if(user.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) user.send(msg);
  });
 }

 /**
  * Remove user from room
  * @param  {String} room
  * @param  {String} channel
  * @param  {Object} socket
  * @return {void}
  */
 function rm(room, channel, socket)
 {
  if(typeof rooms[room] == 'undefined') return;
  if(typeof rooms[room][channel] == 'undefined') return;
  rooms[room][channel] = rooms[room][channel].filter(user => user != socket);
  // redis.unsubscribe(`${room}-${channel}`);
 }

//@Connection socket connection event
 ws.on('connection', function connection(socket, req) {
  socket.isActive = true;
  const f = formatSocketUrl(req.url);
  socket['props'] = addPropToSocket(...f);
  add(...f, socket);
  socket.on('message', msg => send(...f, msg, socket));
  socket.on('pong', () => socket.isActive = true);
  socket.on('close', () => {
   rm(socket.props.room, socket.props.channel, socket);
  });
  redis.on('message', (channel , msg) => {
   const f = channel.split('-');
   send(...f, msg, socket);
  });
 });
```

Comment: Sorry my bad it was in my redis.subscribe() it keeps subcribing when new connection is created so multiple subscribe event will be fired.

Comment: check the filter condition may not working